# Write to log every X time

Tags: c#, logging, timer

I want to write to a log every 3 hours using `System.IO`

There is no matter how the files called. Really, just how can I do that every 3 hours something happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Timer, set its Interval to 3*60*60*1000 and, in Tick event, do what you need.
Remember to stop timer and remove the handler before form or app closing...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer timer = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do what you need
        File.AppendAllText(log_file, your_message);

    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Tick -= timer_Tick;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing from an application that is already going to be running, or you have an application that needs to run every 3 hours and do the log?

If the latter is the case I would just use Windows built in Task Scheduler.  That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a Timer control class. See the below code

```
System.Timers.Timer Auto_Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

 Auto_Timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Auto_Timer_Elapsed);
 Auto_Timer.Interval = (3*3600000); //3 hours time
 Auto_Timer.Enabled = true;

 void Auto_Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     writetolog(Message);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Start a thread, write your log file, sleep for 10 minutes until 3 hours has passed: repeat! Do a time check after every sleep cause sleep only guarantees your thread wont run for x milli-seconds; it may sleep for longer!